# NSString stringWithFormat return type, why is it "id"?

Tags: ios, nsstring, static-methods, stringwithformat

Why does the method `[NSString stringWithFormat]` return an `id` type? From the name I'm expecting it returns a `NSString`, not a generic pointer. Other classes follow this "rule". For example `[NSNumber numberWithInt]` returns a `NSNumber`, not an `id`.

I think it's not even justified from the fact that is something like a factory method.

Comment: For subclassing. `NSMutableString` would require a cast in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree -- you can do a tap dance around why it's the way it is, but ultimately it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention `NSNumber`, this doesn't have any direct subclasses, so it's safe for `numberWithInt:` to return a `NSNumber*`

`NSString*` (and other classes such as `NSSet`) return type `id` because they can have subclasses (`NSMutableString` and `NSMutableSet` respectively), which will inherit this method. As such, these inherited calls need to return an instance of the subclass's type, and due to the rules of method naming, you can't overload based on return type alone. As such, they need a common type between them all, which is `id`.

**Update**: Recent developments mean the keyword `instancetype` is now available. You may have noticed a lot of references to `id` are now replaced with `instancetype`. This keyword provides a hint to the compiler that the return type of the method is the same class of the receiver of the method.

For example (and I stress an example, this may not be the case in the actual framework):

```
NSArray:
- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray*)array;

NSMutableArray:
// Inherits from NSArray

----

// Receiver is NSArray, method belongs in NSArray, returns an NSArray
[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[]];

// Receiver is NSMutableArray, method belongs in NSArray, returns an NSMutableArray
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[]];
```

Comment: Ok, i never thought i could call [NSMutableString stringWithFormat]. Usually i built an empty NSMutableString and then appending formats. My understanding of class hierarchy is biased from Java experience where String is not a super class of StringBuilder.

Comment: The mutable version of a class is always a subclass of it's concrete counterpart. It makes sense for Cocoa, the mutable class is identical to the concrete one, with a few bells and whistles added to allow it to be readwrite, instead of readonly :)

Comment: @WDUK being picky, `NSNumber` is a class cluster, so it has a lot of subclasses, just they are private.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Very true, but in the eyes of the average developer, you don't need to concern yourself with them. Only if you were to subclass or swizzle a particular implementation would you need to (which I don't recommend with NSNumber, you don't want to embroil yourself by messing with it's tagged pointer implementation!)

Answer (score 5):

Because it is a static method on the class NSString and it is assumed to be returning the type of the object being called on. This is also dependent on the type since this can come from an NSMutableString.