# When would an Objective-C factory method not need to return an object of type id?

Tags: objective-c, factory-pattern

I'm confused about the return type of factory methods in Objective-C.

This post: [NSString stringWithFormat return type, why is it "id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278910/nsstring-stringwithformat-return-type-why-is-it-id)  should resolved my confusion. But, the first line of the accepted answer does not make sense to me.

If I can't prevent subclassing (right?), and I can override class methods (ie. the *factory methods*), then don't I have to always return `id`?

Comment: If you want those methods to be subclassed, then yes. If you don't support having those methods subclassed, then no. But also be sure to read http://nshipster.com/instancetype/

Comment: Factory methods never need to return type `id`.  You should return `instancetype`.

Comment: This answer of mine is relevant and perhaps a little clearer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136271/why-does-nsdate-date-return-id/14136588#14136588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an API design decision. Subclassing cannot be prevented, but the API can be designed such as it is strongly discouraged. That's precisely the case of `NSNumber`.

`NSNumber` is a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html), meaning it is an abstract class with several private subclasses. Users of this class are normally not supposed to create their own subclasses, hence the design decision of returning `NSNumber *` instead of `id`.

Note that this cannot be done with other class clusters such as `NSArray` or `NSString`, since they have public subclasses.

`id` is used for flexibility towards subclassing, so not using it is a way of discouraging the clients to subclass that class.

Incidentally, as I already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136271/why-does-nsdate-date-return-id/14136588#14136588), as per today we have a better alternative to the `id` return type, namely `instancetype`. You can read more on the subject [here](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/).

Answer (score 1):

Consider two classes, `ParentClass`, and (one of) its subclasses `ChildClass`.

Compare these factory methods on `ParentClass`.

```
+(instancetype)parent {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

Now, with `ChildClass` being a subclass, we can instantiate empty `ChildClass` objects simply by doing this:

```
ChildClass *child = [ChildClass parent];
```

And we'll actually return an object of type `child`.  Now, you may never use this, and in this case the method name makes it odd (but consider you can do `[NSString string]` and get an `NSString` or do `[NSMutableString string]` and get an `NSMutableString`).

---

Now you know that obviously:

```
+(ParentClass*)parent {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

is problematic because doing `[ChildClass parent]` will return a `ParentClass` object.  Your question asks however, why you can't just override the methods (and the are other alternavites).  You can, but it's messy and means you're duplicating a lot of code you shouldn't be duplicating.

Why have:

```
//ParentClass.m
+(ParentClass*)parent {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

and:

```
//ChildClass.m
+(ChildClass*)parent {
    return [self child];
}

+(ChildClass*)child {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

When you can just use `instancetype` in `ParentClass`?

---

Alternative to overriding the method would be to do this in the `ChildClass.h`:

```
+(ParentClass*)parent __attribute__((unavailable));
```

Which will mean you simply can't do `[ChildClass parent]` (you'll get a warning and your code won't compile).

---

You CAN do either solution, but they're both messy.  Worse, they become a pain to keep up with if you have more than one subclass.

These are the lengths you have to go to in order to fix inherited factory methods that do not have an `id` or `instancetype` return type.  So, if you intend to subclass your class... or even you don't intend to but would like to keep the option open for yourself or anyone else you might distribute your class too, you should stick with the `instancetype` return type for your factory methods.

But if you want to heavily discourage subclassing, as Apple has done for their own reasons with `NSNumber`, you can return and explicit return type.  @Gabriele Petronella's does a good job of explaining the reasons for `NSNumber` in more detail.

---

For the best discussion I've seen on `id` versus `instancetype`, I recommend checking [this link](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/) out.  But essentially, the advantage of `instancetype` over `id` is that the compiler will still do some type checking.

Comment: You should add an explanation of what `instancetype` is and why it is used instead of `id`.

Comment: While the answer provides correct information, I think it misses the OP's point: why is Apple returning `NSNumber *` instead of `id`?

Comment: Hrm.  I guess I didn't realize that seemed to be the main point of the question.  I will elaborate on it some.

Comment: @GP, nhgrif, LN. yes. The specific issue that tripped me was that NSNumber was returned in a factory method. But, all the info explained to me is very helpful. The (weak) type checking in obj-c still makes me feel disoriented.